# Tesseractによる複数pngファイルのOCRテキストのpdf埋め込み出力

Tags: tesseract

Windows 10、Anacondaの仮想環境（Python3.6）にてJupterlabを起動し、PDFファイルに文字データを埋め込むためにTesseractをつかってOCRをしようと試みています。
（[【Python】pdfファイルから文字起こしをしてテキストに変換する方法（tesseract-OCR、pyocr、pdf2image、poppler）](https://punhundon-lifeshift.com/tesseract_ocr_pdf)を参考にしました）

以下のコードを試し、一つのpdfファイルをTesseractで処理可能なpngファイルにするところまではできたのですが、あるディレクトリにある複数のpngファイルをまとめて処理することができません。

出力されるpdfファイルは0byteとなってしまいます。

コマンドラインとして実行しているTesseract部分にforループで生成した変数名を組み込むことは可能でしょうか？

また、そもそもコマンドラインとして実行すべきではないでそうか？(初心者なものでいろいろ混乱しておりすみません)

狙いとしては!tessractの部分でpngファイルと同じ名前のpdfファイルを生成し、それらを1つのpdfファイルにまとめるという形にしたかったのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import shutil
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import re
from pathlib import Path

#pyocrで使われるファイルのパス
poppler_path = 'C:\\Users\\ilab2\\poppler-0.68.0\\bin'

#処理ファイルの入力
input_file = input('ファイルのパスを入力してください。')

names = []
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + poppler_path
pdf_path = Path(input_file)
pages = convert_from_path(input_file)

for page in pages:
    pdf_path = Path(input_file)
    file_name = pdf_path.stem + "_{:02d}".format(pages.index(page)) + ".png"
    # pngで保存
    page.save(str(file_name), "png")
    names.append(str(file_name))
    print(file_name)
    !tesseract filename filename_{:02d}".format(pages.index(page)) -l eng pdf
```

出力は以下のようになりまして、pngファイルはうまく生成され、0byteのpdfファイルが生成されます。

```
ファイルのパスを入力してください。 test.pdf
test_00.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
test_01.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
test_02.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
test_03.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
test_04.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
test_05.png
Warning: Parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Error, cannot read input file filename: No such file or directory
Error during processing.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは`filename`というファイルが無いということで、`tesseract`コマンドへのパラメータ指定のやり方が間違っているのでは？ 入力用.png のファイル名は `file_name` という変数に入っているのでしょうし、pythonの変数を`!`コマンドに渡す時は`{ }`で囲むのでは？ [Passing Values to and from the Shell](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Passing-Values-to-and-from-the-Shell) それから出力ファイル名を作る？用の`"`が1個しか無くて対になっていないのでは？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
コマンドに変数を渡す部分を修正し、tesseractの-cコマンドを使ったところ、無事にpdfを出力できました！ありがとうございます。

new= "ocr_" + file_name
    print(new)
    #config fileがない場合は-cオプションを使う
    !tesseract -l eng -c tessedit_create_pdf=1 {file_name} {new}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**コマンドラインとして実行しているTesseract部分にforループで生成した変数名を組み込むことは可能でしょうか？**

pythonの変数を`!`コマンドに渡す時は`{ }`で囲めば良いでしょう。

[Passing Values to and from the Shell](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Passing-Values-to-and-from-the-Shell)

> Communication in the other direction–passing Python variables into the shell–is possible using the `{varname}` syntax:
> 他の方向での通信、つまりPython変数をシェルに渡すには、次の{varname}構文を使用します。
>
> ```
> In [9]: message = "hello from Python"
>
> In [10]: !echo {message}
> hello from Python
> ```
>
> The curly braces contain the variable name, which is replaced by the variable's contents in the shell command.
> 中括弧には変数名が含まれ、シェルコマンドで変数の内容に置き換えられます。

---

**狙いとしては!tessractの部分でpngファイルと同じ名前のpdfファイルを生成し**

質問時の転記ミスかもしれませんが「pngファイルと同じ名前のpdfファイル」を組み立てる指定が不完全です。
pdfファイル名を作る用の"が1個しか無くて対になっていないのでは？

> `filename_{:02d}".format(pages.index(page))`

---

**それらを1つのpdfファイルにまとめるという形にしたかった**

最後のこの部分はちょっと意味不明です。元々まとまっている1つのpdfファイルがあって、そこから1ページづつ切り出しているのでは？

---

ソースコードの`for`ループ部分を以下のようにすれば、この時点での動作は出来るでしょう。
主な変更部分の直前の行に`##`でコメントを入れています。

```
for page in pages:
    pdf_path = Path(input_file)
    ## 拡張子無しファイル名作成
    file_name = pdf_path.stem + "_{:02d}".format(pages.index(page))
    ## .png ファイル名作成
    png_name = file_name + ".png"
    # pngで保存
    page.save(str(png_name), "png")
    names.append(str(png_name))
    print(png_name)
    ## shellコマンドへpython変数値をパラメータ指定
    !tesseract {png_name} {file_name} -l eng pdf
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
教えて頂いたページを参考に｛｝を使って変数を指定することができました。

＞元々まとまっている1つのpdfファイルがあって、そこから1ページづつ切り出しているのでは？

やりたかったことは「まとまっている1つのpdfファイルをOCRして文字を埋め込む」ということでした。
しかし自分の調べた限りでは、Tesseractで「複数ページのPDFファイルをOCR、文字を埋め込む」という方法がわからず、Web上で紹介されていた「pdfファイルをpngファイルに分割」、「pngファイルをOCR」という部分を組み合わせて処理しました。